# How do I prove that $(1+\frac{1}{2})^{n} \ge 1 + \frac{n}{2}$ for every $n \ge 1$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

How do I prove that $(1+\frac{1}{2})^{n} \ge 1 + \frac{n}{2}$ for every $n \ge 1$

My base case is $n=1$ 
Inductive step is $n=k$ 
Assume $n=k+1$

$(\frac{3}{2})^{k} \times \frac{3}{2} \ge (1 + \frac{k+1}{2})$

I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_inequality

Answer (score 3):

Let $P(n):(1+x)^n\ge 1+nx$

Clearly $P(n)$ is true for $n=1$

Let $P(n)$ is true for $n=m\implies (1+x)^m\ge 1+mx$

$\implies (1+x)^{m+1}\ge (1+mx)(1+x)=1+(m+1)x+mx^2\ge 1+(m+1)x$ if $m\ge0$  and $x$ is real

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use binomial formula: $(a+b)^n=...$ and take first two terms.

Comment: at which step should I use the binomial theorem?

Comment: @DiscreteGenius: $(a+b)^n=a^n+na^{n-1}b+(\textrm{other positive terms}) \geq a^n+na^{n-1}b$. Here I assume that $a,b \geq 0$.