# Generalized Bernoulli's inequality

Tags: inequality, induction

I was able to prove Bernoulli's inequality, easily by simple induction.
However, I'm not sure how to prove the generalized inequality (generalized = for each sequence of numbers $i=1,\ldots,n$):

$$\prod\limits_{i = 1}^n {(1 + {x_i})}  \ge 1 + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{x_i}},\qquad {x_i} \ge 0$$

How do you prove it? Thanks!

Comment: Simply expand the product?

Comment: Or induction again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$P(n):(1+x_1)(1+x_2)\cdots(1+x_n)\ge1+\sum_{1\le i\le n}x_i$$

Clearly, $P(n)$ holds for $n=1$

Let $P(n)$ holds for $n=m$

$$\implies (1+x_1)(1+x_2)\cdots(1+x_m)\ge1+\sum_{1\le i\le m}x_i$$

For $n=m+1,$

$$ (1+x_1)(1+x_2)\cdots(1+x_m)(1+x_{m+1})\ge(1+\sum_{1\le i\le m}x_i)(1+x_{m+1})$$
$$=1+\sum_{1\le i\le m+1}x_i+x_{m+1}\sum_{1\le i\le m}x_i\ge1+\sum_{1\le i\le m+1}x_i$$ as $x_i>0\forall i\in[1,n]$

Comment: @captaindragon, my pleasure. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535948/how-do-i-prove-that-1-frac12n-ge-1-fracn2-for-every-n-ge-1